# Why is the constructor not working in the code below?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, abstracttablemodel

Here I want to allocate number of rows in a table dynamically using constructor.
datamodel is the class and datamodel(int count) method assigns no.of row.

```
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class datamodel extends AbstractTableModel{
    int row1;
    datamodel(int count){

        row1 = count;
        count = 0;
    }

    private String[] columnNames = {"Sl No","Material Code", "Material Name", "Select", "Received QTY", "Unit", "To Be Delivered", "PO No", "PO Sl"};//new String[9];
    //table has 100 rows and 9 columns
    private Object[][] data = new Object[row1][9]; 


    public int getColumnCount() { return columnNames.length; }
    public int getRowCount() { return data.length;}
    public String getColumnName(int col) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return columnNames[col];
    }

    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return data[row][col];
    }

    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int row, int col) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        data[row][col] = aValue;
        fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
    }

    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    public Class getColumnClass(int col) {
        if((col == 4) || (col == 6))
            return Double.class;
            //return getValueAt(0, c).getClass();
        else if(col == 3)
            return Boolean.class;
        else
            return String.class;
    }
}
```

this is an abstracttablemodel where I want to pass the number of rows to the datamodel.

Comment: And where You are calling your constructor and how?

Comment: As an aside, use `@Override` consistently.

Answer (score 5):

```
int row1;
datamodel(int count){   
    row1 = count;
    count = 0;
}
```

You're setting the *local variable* `count` to zero. That has no effect on the field `row1`.

---

Now, after having a closer look at your code. Strong advice: indent your code, stick to naming conventions an collect all field declarations at the top of the file. Then it's easier for us to understand the code..

```
int row1;
private Object[][] data = new Object[row1][9];

datamodel(int count) {
    row1 = count;
    count = 0;
}
```

What you want to do: pass the value with the constructor so that the array gets initialized. Your approach won't work, because the array is created *before* the constructor method get's executed. So you always have a Object[0][9], regardless what you pass with the constructor.

You should create the array *inside* the constructor method instead:

```
int row1;
private Object[][] data;

datamodel(int count) {
    row1 = count;
    data = new Object[count][9];
}
```